# Wood Staining in a Garage

Tags: wood, ventilation, staining

I am working in the garage with the garage door open as I am working for ventilation. My garage also has gym equipment in it. Am I able to use the garage again soon after or do I have to wait a day or so?

Comment: Will the stained wood remain in the garage?

Comment: No, it will be removed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've removed the stained project material, the vapor will clear out as soon as you allow it to through adequate ventilation. Some slight lingering odor may remain, but it shouldn't be enough to cause health concerns.